# L(q,p)# L(p,q) = surgery on pq-torus knot complement

Tags: knot-theory

I am trying to solve one of Rolfsen exercice. That is prove that the connected sum $L(q,p)\# L(p,q)$ can be obtain by surgery on the complement of the  pq-torus knot  in $S^3$. I am doing it using link calculus but I get stuck. How should I approach the problem ?